# Uipath dropdown navigation

Tags: webforms, automation, dropdown, uipath

I am trying to automate a process where the page has 4 fields one below the other and I need to select an option from these dropdowns.
I am only able to automate the first one but unable to make the bot go to the second and third.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to provide an adequate answer without more details. Can you provide an example of what you are trying to automate (link to, or mockup source, image). As well as details of what you have tried already, steps of your workflow, and code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by doing the following steps:

1. Create an `Array<String>` and fill it with the dropdown options. E.g `{"A", "B", "C", "D"}`.
2. Use the 'Click' activity on the dropdown menu
3. Get the 'selecter' by going to the UiExplorer and make sure to enable the `aaname` property, which is by default set to whatever is currently selected. Let's assume it's '---' for this example.
4. Loop over your `Array<String>` from point 1 and change the 'Click' activity's selector's `"aaname='---'"` to `"aaname='" + currentString + "'"`. Hence making it dynamic.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1. Use `Find Children` Activity to generate a List of the 4 dropdowns in the page. (To be able to achieve this, you would need to grab a parent element of the dropdowns using the `UiExplorer` and then in the `Filter` option use the tag for the Drop down.)
2. Have a `Dictionary(Of UiElement, String)` (or any other similar data type) ready to keep track of the `UiElement`s of the DropDowns and the options that should be selected:

   `DropDownA (UiElement variable) -> "United States of America"`

   `DropDownB (UiElement variable) -> "Florida"`

   `DropDownC (UiElement variable) -> "Orange County"`

   `DropDownD (UiElement variable) -> "Orlando"`

If you prefer to do it sequentially one by one instead of a loop, you could do it as well by creating 4 `UiElement` variables in the workflow and adding the proper selector generated from the explorer and 4 variables for the expected values of the options.

However, having them grouped in some sort of collection would allow you to apply simple logic similar to the following snippet:

```
  For Each of the UiElements (Keys in the Dictionary)
      Use Click Activity to Open DropDown
      While highlighted option does not equal the value
          Use Send Hot Key Activity (Arrow Button Down)
      Use Send Hoy Key Activity (Enter)
```

Also, if you post your xaml to see what could be happening that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

1. For Each of the UiElements (Keys in the Dictionary)
2. Use Click Activity to Open DropDown
3. While highlighted option does not equal the value
4. Use Send Hot Key Activity (Arrow Button Down)
5. Use Send Hoy Key Activity (Enter)